# My middleware is working fine but not redirecting to another route

Tags: next.js

I've encountered a situation in my code where everything appears to be functioning correctly without any error messages. However, I'm facing an issue where the response is not redirecting to another route as it should be. I'm seeking assistance to resolve this problem.

I have already checked for any coding errors or exceptions, and none seem to be present. Despite this, the expected redirection to a different route within my web application is not happening. I'm puzzled by this behavior and need guidance on troubleshooting and resolving this issue.

```
import { sign, verify } from "next-token";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
export async function middleware(req, res) {
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/sdp") && req.method == "POST") {
    let admins = await adminreq();
    let clientData = await req.formData();
    let user = admins[0];
    console.log(user.username, user.password);
    let uname = clientData.get("username");
    let pwd = clientData.get("password");
    console.log(uname, pwd);
    if (user.username === uname && user.password === pwd) {
      let jwt = await sign({ name: uname }, process.env.SECRET);
      console.log(jwt);
      let res = NextResponse.next();
      res.cookies.set("jwt", jwt, { secure: true });
      NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", req.url));
    } else {
      NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/sdp", req.url));
    }
  }
}

async function adminreq() {
  try {
    let req = await fetch(process.env.API, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        admin: true,
      }),
    });
    let res = await req.json();
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    return { error: true, message: err.message };
  }
}
```

The above code is from middleware.js and below code is from page.js inside sdp directory

```js
export default function Login(){
    return(
    <div className="container shadow-4 rounded mt-3 mb-3 p-3 border border-primary bg-gradient-to-r from-violet-200 to-pink-200 sm:w-100 md:w-80 lg:w-80">
        <h1 className="h1 text-center w-100">Admin Login</h1><hr />
        <form method="post" action="/sdp">
            <label htmlFor="name">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name='username' id="name" className="form-control mb-2" />
            <label htmlFor="pwd">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name='password' className="form-control mb-2" />
            <button className="btn btn-primary rounded-pill bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-400 to-cyan-400" type='submit'>Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware) file is in the right place in your project folder structure, you need to return the `NextReponse`. For example, this line:

```js
NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", req.url))
```

should be:

```js
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", req.url))
```

Comment: yes my middle ware is in right place in `src` directory.
i tried adding return statement but not working.

Comment: How you are testing it? By changing the URL in the browser search bar and hitting enter?

Comment: i'm testing it submitting a url encoded form .

Comment: You cannot change the browser URL after a JavaScript request is made through something like `fetch` (which always expects a response back, and then you can redirect but on the client).

Comment: This is not fetch request this is direct form submit (x-www-form-urlencoded) .

Comment: Can you edit your question and show that part?

Comment: ok sure  updated

Comment: Are you using [server actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions)? Because I don't think you can use an `action` just like that in Next.js